# Any way to conditionalize variable in jsonencoded data?

Tags: terraform

Say I have the simplified following snippet to create a task definition as json.

```
...
task_container_definitions = jsonencode([{
    name : var.name,
    image : "${var.image}:${var.tag}",
    cpu : var.cpu,
    memory : var.memory,
}])
...
```

Say I want to add a variable to optionally create an additional definition so it looks something like this:

```
variable "another_definition" {
  type    = any
  default = {}
}

...
task_container_definitions = jsonencode([{
    name : var.name,
    image : "${var.image}:${var.tag}",
    cpu : var.cpu,
    memory : var.memory,
},
var.another_definition
])
```

And define it as follows.

```
  another_definition = {
      name      = "another_container"
      image     = "another_container"
      cpu       = 10
      memory    = 512
      essential = true
  }
```

I am able to get this to to output as expected as long as the variable is defined.

```
...
+ {
    + cpu          = 10
    + essential    = true
    + image        = "another_container"
    + memory       = 512
    + name         = "another_container"
  },
```

But if the variable is not defined, I see empty `{}` added to the output when I do a `terraform plan`, which is not what I expect. I have tried using `null` as well as the default but get an error.

```
...
+ {},
```

Is there a way to toggle this variable off so that if it is not defined then it doesn't show up in the outputted json definition? Is there a better approach than what I am attempting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was a little confused at first as to what you were asking, thinking that you were asking for the functionality of [the `merge` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/merge.html), and I mention that only in case I was right the first time, but I think I now understand your problem as that you want this `task_container_definitions` to have either one or two elements, depending on whether `var.another_definition` is set.

There's no single function for that particular situation, but I think we can combine some language features together to get that result.

First, let's decide that the variable being *set* means that it has a non-`null` value, and thus its default value should be `null` to represent the "unset" case:

```
variable "another_definition" {
  type    = any
  default = null

  validation {
    # The time constraint above is looser than we really
    # want, so this validation rule also enforces that
    # the caller can't set this to something inappropriate,
    # like a single string or a list.
    condition = (
      var.another_definition != null ?
      can(keys(var.another_definition)) :
      true
    )
    error_message = "Additional task container definition must be an object."
  }
}
```

In Terraform it's a pretty common situation to need to convert between a value that might be null and a list that might have zero or one elements, or vice-versa, and so Terraform has some language features to help with that. In this case we can use a [splat expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/splat.html) to concisely represent that. Let's see how that looks in `terraform console` first just to give a sense of what we're achieving with this:

```
$ terraform console
> null[*]
[]
> "hello"[*]
[
  "hello",
]
> { object = "example" }[*]
[
  {
    "object" = "example"
  },
]
```

Notice that when I applied the `[*]` operator to `null` it returned an empty list, but when I applied it to these other values it converted them to a single-element list. This is how the `[*]` operator behaves when you apply it to something that isn't a list; see the splat operator docs if you want to learn about the different behavior for lists, which isn't really relevant here because of the validation rule I added above which prevents the `var.another_definition` value from being a list.

Another tool we have in our Terraform toolbox here is [the `concat` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/concat.html), which takes one or more lists and returns a single list with the input elements all concatenated together in the given order. We can use this to combine your predefined list that's populated from `var.name`, `var.cpu`, etc with the zero-or-one element list created by `[*]`, in order to create a list with their one or two elements:

```
locals {
  task_container_definitions = concat(
    [
      name   = var.name
      image  = "${var.image}:${var.tag}"
      cpu    = var.cpu
      memory = var.memory
    ],
    var.another_definition[*],
  )
  task_container_definitions_json = jsonencode(local.task_container_definitions)
}
```

If any of the arguments to `concat` are empty lists then they are effectively ignored altogether, because they contribute no elements to the result, and so this achieves (what I hope is) the desired result, by making the "other definition" appear in the result only when it's set to something other than `null`.

Comment: Hrm, it seems to work when I have `another_definition` defined but when the variable isn't set (null) tf errors `Error: Invalid value for variable ... Additional task container definition must be an object.This was checked by the validation rule at vars.tf:177,3-13.`

Comment: Doing some debugging, if I replace `var.another_definition[*],` with `[]` it works like you say, and shows no changes.

Comment: Oh yes, of course... I forgot to include the `null` case in the validation condition because I reworked it after I initially wrote it. I'll edit the answer to include an explicit exception for that.

Comment: Ah yep that fixed the original error, thanks. Now I am seeing expeted behavior when `another_definition` is defined but the original container definition is being removed when `another_definition` isn't set.